# What is the difference between "he helped me out" and "he helped"?

Tags: grammaticality, difference, word-difference

What is the difference between **he helped me out** and **he helped**? In what context can we use them?

Comment: Both mean the same. Its the way how you say it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Help out*](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/help#help_1__119) is a phrasal verb that means "to help somebody, especially in a difficult situation."

> He's always willing to help out.

> When I bought the house, my sister helped me out with a loan.

Answer (score 9):

"He helped me": I did something, and he did more which added to what I did.

"He helped me out": I was in trouble, and he acted to get me out of trouble.

For example "He helped me clean the room": I did some cleaning, and he also did some cleaning. "He helped me out cleaning the room": I would have been in trouble for not having cleaned the room, and he got me out of trouble by doing all the work for me.

Answer (score 3):

They both mean the same thing, It is just their constructions that are different.

> He helped me out during the exam when I was sick last year.
>   He helped me  during the exam when I was sick last year

> He helped me clean the room.
>   He helped me out cleaning my room.

> He helped me out with the math problem.
>   He helped me with the math problem.

> He helped me decide which college I am supposed to attend.
>   He helped me out deciding which college I am supposed to attend.